# Enviar informacion de un datagridvew a otro datagridview

Tags: c#

Agradecería mucho si me ayudaran con esta duda que tengo.

Actualmente tengo un `textbox` que me busca artículos en una base de datos y las muestra en el `datagridview` de nombre "datalistado". Quiero que una vez mostrados los resultados, si yo le doy doble click a alguno, me lo envíe a otro `datagridview` llamado "datatotal".

Este es mi código actual:

```
 private void datalistado_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datalistado.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value))
                {

                    DataGridViewRow fila = new DataGridViewRow();
                    fila.CreateCells(datatotal);
                    fila.Cells[1].Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                    fila.Cells[2].Value = row.Cells[2].Value;
                    datatotal.Rows.Add(fila);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Sistema Restaurante", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Comment: Y cual es el problema con este codigo?

Comment: Creo que deberias consultar este link @leandrotuttini tiene un buen ejemplo http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/04/datagridview-pasar-registros-entre.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre solucionarlo gracias a sus comentarios! Esto fue lo que terminé haciendo:

```
private void datalistado_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int rowId = datatotal.Rows.Add();

    // Tomando la fila
    DataGridViewRow row = datatotal.Rows[rowId];

    // Añadir datos a la fila!
    row.Cells["Nombre"].Value = datalistado.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
    row.Cells["Precio"].Value = datalistado.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
}
```